# json populate table view controller wont work

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch

I've been following a tutorial on youtube on how to load external data from a database on to a iOS application. I understand the concept and how it works etc. But I'm having an error even though I'm following the video and from looking online it seems to be a common error.

```
- (void) retrieveData
{
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: getDataURL];
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data  options:kNilOptions error:nil];

//set up our cities array
citiesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// loop through our json array
for (int i =0; i< jsonArray.count; i++)
{
    //create our city object
    NSString * cID = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString * cName = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cityName"];
    NSString * cState = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cityState"];
    NSString * cPopulation = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cityPopulation"];
    NSString * cCountry = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"country"];

    // Add the city object to our cities array
   [citiesArray addObject:[[City alloc]initWithCityName:cName andCityState:cState andCityCountry:cCountry andCityPopulation:cPopulation andCityID:cID]];

}
//reload our table view
[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

The code fails on the third line.

```
jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data  options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

Why is that? Any suggestions? The jsonArray has already been created, so I can't understand why it won't work.

Comment: what error you getting ?

Comment: what the error you got

Comment: Please tell us the error and also give us an example of what you are passing in.

Comment: and we need to see the JSON string.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil' this is the error message i receive

Comment: heres the link  showing what is being parsed http://www.conkave.com/iosdemos/json.php it's from a tutorial i just want to make this work then i can edit it for my own purposes

Comment: Then data is nil, e.g. there is nothing in data. Stick a break point on it and log the value of data to the console.

Comment: Also, the above URL just generates a 404 Error.

Comment: http://www.conkave.com/iosdemos/json.php sorry wrong link this one is correct

Comment: I stuck a breakpoint and thats where it was failing, i don't understand why it works in the tutorial video and by everyones comments on the video. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code & i don't think there is any error.

I hope you've declared `NSMutableArray *jsonArray` in header (.h) file.

- If you getting error in thos line :

  jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data  options:kNilOptions error:nil];
  than replace kNilOptions with simply nil.
- If you getting crash than it might be because nil data. In that case you have to put condition before you store data in array something like this :

if (data != nil)
{

```
   jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data  options:nil error:nil];}
```

Hope it'll help.

Comment: i have declared it, in the header i'll try your method now thanks

Comment: @steff i got your issue you getting nil data so you have to just put the condition as above.

Comment: where exactly do i put it because when i tried i got a warning saying "incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'void*' to parameter of type' NSJSONReadingOptiong' (aka 'enum NSJSONReadingOptions')

Comment: you already have this line right ?    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data  options:nil error:nil];}

Comment: just you need to place it in condition i given

Comment: i changed my third line to jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data  options:nil error:nil]; like you said but as soon i done that i got the yellow triangle saying the error above ^^. could you please elaborate

Comment: sure how do i upload a screen shot ?

Comment: found the error was a typo mistake at the top. Thanks sorry for all the trouble

Comment: i would because youve been really helpful but i dont have a high enough reputation once i do i'll come back and upvote you